# Help me solve a simple linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following ODE (I'm a rookie in math, sorry).

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = - x(t) + 0.9 x(t) + 5
$$

my solution is this

$$
x(t) = \frac{5}{0.9-1} e^{t(0.9-1)}
$$

when I plot the graph of x(t), it first rises sharply and then converges to x=50. My question is why does x(t) always rise? If I graph the derivative (dx/dt, above), the straight line crosses the horizontal axis at 50, so at t = 50 the function x(t) should start decreasing. And in my case I doesn't. Why? Please help.
[image]

Comment: $0.9-1=-0.1$ btw.

Comment: why not $$\frac{dx}{dt}=5-\frac{x(t)}{10}$$?

Comment: First: $x(t) = (x_0-50) e^{-0.1t} + 50$  Wherever you start $x(t)$ decays approaching $50$ (increasing if it starts below $50,$ decreasing if it starts above $50.$  But, it never crosses 50.  The closer that $x(t)$ gets to 50, the closer $x'(t)$ gets to $0.$  As $x'(t)$ approaches $0,$ it becomes impossible for $x(t)$ to cross that barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5-0.1x(t)$ indeed "crosses the horizontal axis" at $x=50$. But that doesn't tell you anything about what arises at $t=50$. You are confusing the variables.

Actually, $x$ *never* reaches the value $50$ (otherwise $\dot x=0$ would imply a constant function), so that $\dot x$ never changes sign and $x(t)$ is monotonic, whatever the initial conditions. This is confirmed by the solution given by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: the exponential is monotonic, and so is it's derivative.

Comment: Thank you all very much. That was very helpful!